# can't add relational data with angular and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs, mongoose

I have a view where I list 'Transporters'. A transporter has hany 'Deliveries', so I'd like to add Deliveries to respective Transporters.

I am using express, mongoose and angular.js. I have two model definitions:

```
// app/models/transporter.js
var Delivery = require('./delivery');

var transporterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    natl_id_num: String,
    phone: String,
    deliveries: [Delivery]
});

var Transporter = mongoose.model('Transporter', transporterSchema);


// app/models/delivery.js
var Transporter = require('./transporter.js');

var deliverySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    transporter: [Transporter],
    amount: Number
})

var Delivery = mongoose.model('Delivery', deliverySchema);
```

Then I have a view with an input field and button for each transporter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in transporters track by $index">
    <td>{{t.name}}</td>
    <td>{{t.deliveries.length}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="amount" ng-model="deliveryAmount">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="addDelivery(deliveryAmount, t)">Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I click the button I would like to add a new delivery for that Transporter. Here is the corresponding controller:

```
$scope.addDelivery = function(deliveryAmount, transporter){
            var data = {};
            data.date = Date.now();
            data.amount = deliveryAmount;
            data.transporter = transporter;
            console.log('data equals: ' + data.transporter);

            $http({
                url: '/api/deliveries', 
                data: data,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    $('input').val('');
                    console.log(data + ' added');
                })
                .error(function(data){
                    console.log('couldn\'t post delivery: ' + err);
                });
        };
```

However, when I list all deliveries, the transporter and amount properties are not there. In the controller there is:

```
$http.get('/api/deliveries')
        .success(function(data){
            // add all deliveries to deliveries scope
            $scope.deliveries = data;
        })
```

And in the view there is:

```
<p ng-repeat='d in deliveries'>{{ d }}</p>
```

But that outputs:

```
{"_id":"52f9f0e5156c0f6303d846ef","__v":0,"transporter":[],"date":"2014-02-11T09:44:05.619Z"}
```

Instead of showing the amount and the transporter as specified with the `addDelivery` function

My REST API for deliveries is shown here:

```
// all deliveries
app.get('/api/deliveries', function(req, res){
    Delivery.find(function(err, deliveries){
        if(err) res.send(err);

        res.json(deliveries);
    });
});

// create delivery
app.post('/api/deliveries', function(req, res){
    Delivery.create({
        date: req.body.date,
        transporter: req.body.transporter,
        amount: req.body.amount
    }, function(err, delivery){
        if(err) res.send(err);

        Delivery.find(function(err, deliveries){
            if(err) res.send(err);

            res.json(deliveries);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So you know your problem is that you are not getting back the JSON you expect. But what you do not show is how that is being fetched and transformed from your "/api/deliveries" endpoint. From that point you should see all your angular code has nothing to do with this part of the problem, and that you have excluded the important part. You'll do better to edit this and read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok my bad. added the express api routes

Comment: Pull out the angular stuff. Really. It's you are asking people to read through a whole load of document that isn't about the problem you are having. You can also add value by including a sample of the JSON you expect to be seeing in the response and more important again is what the data looks like in mongo. So not just the schema, the data as well. If the angular part becomes a problem, then that's another question. But you did read the page on the link didn't you :)

Comment: Sorry if that sounds harsh. But focus the subject and change your title accordingly and you'll get a better response. There is already one thing apparent in the additional posting. Let more people see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are expecting too much magic from both Mongoose and your transformation to JSON, and this is why things are not working as you expect. Let's focus on the code covering your '/api/deliveries' endpoint.

Here your making a call to find (with no query) which would, from a Mongo point of view, return a **cursor** to the results of *all* of the documents in this collection. This may be fine for now, but you should be looking at filtering this.

Now you know you have comprised your schema with a definition for `deliverySchema` containing an array of `transporterSchema` entries. And most importantly you have assigned these to **two** models. That effectively means one collection for `deliveries` and one for `transporter` documents.

In order to get the data, from a MongoDB point of view, for each `Delivery` document, we have to go back with another request ( or requests ) to the server to get the `Transporter` document(s). Now part of Mongoose is that you can *kind of* do this transparently in coding and access that sub-document array just as if it were a normal array on the object. But in truth it isn't and that **magic** happening is hiding away the real operations.

Hence your problem. You haven't **really** pulled all the data that you intend to serialize to JSON. What you have is a **cursor**, and though there is a *partial* implementation to do the serialize, it does not really have the *smarts* to know exactly what it has to do to get to the rest of the data.

In brief. You can't just pass in the cursor to your JSON serialize call, you need to traverse and save the data as a `var` that you can serialize.

The additional part of the answer is maybe you actually want [Embedded Documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/docs/embedded-documents.html), and that should be worthwhile reading. After all there is little point to using MongoDB if you're just going to use the storage the same way as you do with relational.

This is deliberately a "no code" response as I think it is important to understand the concepts of **why** things didn't turn out like you expected. You should also have a good base on where to start changing things so they will work.

Comment: yeah awesome, it's all about the concepts

Comment: Hope you like the edit as well. Maybe someone might have something else to add when it's a bit clearer to see.